# About wcf rest return list

Tags: wcf

Server side interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetCardInfoByCardNumber/?cardNumber={cardNumber}&SerialNumber={SerialNumber}&token={token}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
IList<Cards> GetCardInfoByCardNumber(string cardNumber, string SerialNumber, string token);
```

Server side implementation:

```
public IList<Cards> GetCardInfoByCardNumber(string cardNumber, string SerialNumber, string token)
{
   if (BaseClass.HasPermission(token))
      return cm.GetCardInfoByCardNumber(cardNumber, SerialNumber);
   else
      return null;
}
```

Client side:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestResWCF();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static List<Cards> TestResWCF()
    {
        List<Cards> a = null;
        string ServiceUri = "http://192.168.15.18:8089/GetCardInfoByCardNumber/?cardNumber=HH-120109-017&SerialNumber=&token=123456";

        WebClient proxy = new WebClient();

        proxy.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        proxy.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler
            (
             (s, e) =>
             {
                 Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(e.Result));
                 DataContractJsonSerializer obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Cards>));
                 a = obj.ReadObject(stream) as List<Cards>;
             }
            );

        proxy.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(ServiceUri));

        return a;
    }
```

`List<Cards>` a return empty string always! How to return data? Thank you very much!

Do you have any example? sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the code for the "Cards" and "Card" classes?

I'm very sure that most likely, it is not decorated with [DataContract] and [DataMember] properly. You may have decorated the type with [DataContract], but forgotten to annotate the members you want with [DataMember]. Or alternatively, you may not have decorated them at all, and something else is happening behind the scenes. In 99% of the scenarios, misdecoration or improper decoration or mis-initialization of the serializer is the reason this error occurs.

If you did decorate it properly, there may be some other problems. It's hard to tell with 100% certainty from just the detail you've provided, so I'd enable tracing to generate tracing logs (that you can then view/share with SvcTraceViewer) and turn on debug exceptions (by turning on the includeExceptionDetailInFaults setting).